# Can I add a custom button to MetaMask or other Ethereum wallets that can be clicked on to call a custom contract function? If so, how?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, myetherwallet

I am building an ERC20 token that has special functions that I want the client to be able to interact with. Is there anyway I can do this? I'm pretty sure I have to use web3.js but I don't know where to start. I tried looking it up and have gone everywhere but no one seems to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can do it. Look what LARVALABS did with they projects :
https://www.larvalabs.com/cryptopunks
https://meebits.larvalabs.com/

Yes web3js is a good choice about it. I advice you to follow basic tutorial for Dapp interaction.

Remix IDE is a good software in browser that can help you interact with your smart contract. Then when it's deployed you have to code your own web3js function to interact with contract.

Comment: Could you please link some tutorials for Dapp interaction? My goal is to be able to have a button alongside "send" in wallets such as MetaMask. Are there any tutorials you could recommend that would help me with this?